# How do I get design input on a paper cut?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I'm working designing a fix for a paper cut, and I'd like to get someone to approve it before I try to implement it. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process you follow for getting design approval depends on what app your working on.

### Ubuntu/Canonical apps

These are apps that are originally build and distributed in Ubuntu. These include, but are not limited to, Ubuntu Software Centre, Ubuntu One Control Panel, and Unity.

To request design input on a paper cut in one of these, you should follow these steps:

- Make sure the bug report has a paper cut task open on it. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231178/how-do-i-report-a-paper-cut) for details on how to go about this.
- Make sure you have proposed a design fix in the comments of the report since it's a little rude to not do some sort of work before asking others to get involved.
- Assign the paper cut task to Nick Tait, a project manager on the Design Team at Canonical. Click on the exclamation mark in the 'Assigned to' field on the paper cuts task. If it's already assigned to the Paper Cuts Ninjas, then unassign them first.

[image]

- The assignee you want is `jnick-tait`

[image]

- The paper cut is now assigned to Nick Tait.

[image]

You have just requested design input on a Canonical app.

### Gnome apps

These are the apps that are developed upstream by the Gnome project, and include, but are not limited to, Nautilus, Rhythmbox and Gedit.

Gnome apps each have an individual maintainer who is contactable via the development mailing list for that app. The full list of Gnome mailing lists can be found [here](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo). Use your browser's search feature to find the app your looking for since there's a lot of lists there.

Send a message to the list, mentioning that your part of the One Hundred Paper Cuts project and are looking for input from the developers on a design fix. Make sure you've come up with an idea yourself before approaching the developers since you're the one working on the bug and it's a bit rude to go to them unprepared.

Comment: This needs revising.  The new consensus is to NEVER assign a bug to someone unless (1) you assign it to yourself, or (2) someone said to assign the bug to them because they can't assign themselves at the time.